# How to convert CTime to integer?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, ctime, cfile

I need to get modify date from a file.

```
    CFileStatus stat;
    CFile::GetStatus(strFilePath, stat);
```

It returns 1585557924 to be CTime. (it look like a timestamp)

```
    stat.m_mtime
```

I have a lot of file and I need to get modify date from each file as timestamp then sum all timestamp.

But It cannot convert stat.m_mtime to integer.

```
   int sum_timestamp = 0;
   sum_timestamp +=  (int)stat.m_mtime;
```

It error like these.

```
   'no suitable conversion function from "ATL::CTime"to"int"exists'
```

Comment: What kind of integer? Unix-style seconds-since-epoch? JS-style milliseconds-since-epoch? Something else? Is [`GetAsSystemTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/ctime-class?view=vs-2019#getassystemtime) sufficient for your use case?

Comment: "How to convert stat.m_mtime to integer ?" - what do you mean? It *is* an integer. 1585557924 is a perfectly valid integer. How you *interpret* it is a different question.

Comment: What you have there is the number of seconds since the 'epoch' (1st January 1970), and it is already an integral type (specifically a `time_t`, these days, usually, a `long`).  So what did you want to convert it to, and why?

Comment: I try to declare int variable for keeping this value. But it cannot to assign 'm_mtime' to a variable.
int sum_timestamp = 0;
sum_timestamp =  (int)stat.m_mtime;

but it error like these
'no suitable conversion function from "ATL::CTime"to"int"exists'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are compiling in 64 bits, you can get a unix timestamp from `CTime` using `GetTime()`, which is is a `__time64_t_` (= `__int64` = `long long`).
Ex:

```
   long long sum_timestamp = 0;
   sum_timestamp += stat.m_mtime.GetTime();
```